# Is there any place like "Wertinberge" in Germany?

Tags: germany, palaeography, place-names

The 1850 census taker did their best for Mary Fox's birthplace, but I can't really decipher it:

[image: screenshot of birthplace name]

I strongly suspect this is somewhere in Germany, because family lore says Mary Fox and her family came from Germany. However, "Worthinberge" (Ancestry's attempted transcription) doesn't appear to exist, nor "Wertimberge" (my best guess).

What was the birthplace for Mary Fox supposed to say?

Comment: The problem is that there's clearly a dot after the t, suggesting a i letter.

Comment: To Swabians? Absolutely! Their home "Württemberg", see lejonet's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read *Woitimberge* or *Wertimberge* here. Both are not place names.

I guess the census taker did not understand the place name correctly and spelling the place name might also be influenced from local dialect.

European place names are listed in the [GOV (Geschichtliches Orts-Verzeichnis)](http://gov.genealogy.net/search/index). You can search it using the [wildcard character *](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) (but you have to start with a regular letter).

The most likely place seems [Württemberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCrttemberg), a historical territory.
The only place starting with *W* and ending *-berge* that comes to my mind is the city [Wittenberge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittenberge) (don’t confuse it with Luther’s [Wittenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittenberg)). As I learned from the GOV, there is not just the city of Wittenberge (in Brandenburg), but also a much smaller [town with the same name](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/WITRGEJO33WD) (in Lower-Saxony).

Comment: Württemberg existed around the time of this census entry (mid nineteenth century) and seems a very plausible place of origin for the Fox (probably Fuchs originally) family. Thank you!

Comment: For comparison, here's a search I ran on the new Meyers Gaz website: http://www.meyersgaz.org/search.aspx?search=W*rt*berg*
See http://www.lostcousins.com/newsletters2/meyersgaz.pdf for an overview of the website.

Comment: Not disputing either the methodology or the result, but English-speakers often confuse berg and burg. Wildcard searches should take this into account.

Comment: As native speaker, I can imagine the Fox' family speaking dialect (probably Swabian) and then "Württemberg" would sound very much like the "Wertimberge" we see written here, at least to the ears of an English speaking listener..

Answer (score 0):

Baden_ Wurtenberg is a province in South Central Germany. I also have old ancestors from this area.